# Why do browsers still spoof user agents?

Tags: browser, user-agent

I know that browsers originally spoofed user agents in order to allow for feature detection. But I am wondering why they *still* do so. I don't think user agent spoofing has a place in the modern era of standards compliance; what is basically a browser nirvana for web developers compared to the situation during the infancy of the web.

Someone will probably say that it's for backwards compatibility for all the old code out there. Is that the only reason? After all this time I think browser vendors would be looking beyond those sites with old code. Is this being worked on, or are these user agents just forgotten relics from tougher times for browsers?

Additionally, most feature detection these days seems to be done with JavaScript, which makes part of the feature detection use case for a user agent irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Because nowadays we have multiples possibles user agents like Iphone5s, Galaxy SIII, IPad 2  and so on. Because that it is sometimes necessary to handler the site features in different ways to specific rules for example.

Think in the scenario with user requirements look like that:

- The site should be able to chat with customer only for tablet.
- In mobile should not be able because it is smaller.

Thus, because we have multiples devices, we sometimes have to handler in different ways to give for user a great experience.

Comment: That is a normal use case for user agents, not for user agent spoofing. An example of spoofing is how many browsers still have "Mozilla" in the user agent even though Netscape does not even exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that they do. Some smaller browsers user agents might not be recognized by a server so they announce themselves as one of the major ones so they don't get ignored or treated as malicious but, otherwise, you are right; there is no need to do so and the major ones don't.

Comment: They do, at least somewhat. Here's Chrome on my MacBook Pro: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36`. I don't see why there should be "Mozilla" or "KHTML, like Gecko" in the user agent string. Chrome is not Netscape, nor does it run on Gecko.

Comment: @MJWilliams Because Chrome used webkit and now a fork of webkit called Blink but webkit had its beginnings in KHTML which was based on ... Gecko.